# Jquery Treeview Expand and Collapse node on text click with persist cookie option

Tags: jquery, treeview

I would like to expand and collapse the nodes when i click +/- symbols and also when i click the text (hyperlink) next to each symbol. I want to collapse the previous node and expand the node which i clicked. I am using the following method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // first example
    $("#navigation").treeview({
        persist: "cookie", //I want to store the state and come back to the state when i reload the page.
        collapsed: true, //I want to collapse all the nodes when i load.
        unique:true //I want to open only one node at a time
    });
});
```

I have tried lot of options but none of them worked. Please help me.

My HTML is:

```
 <ul id="navigation" class="treeview">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Marketing</a>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">Joysticks</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Intel</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Microsoft</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Sony</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">Laptops</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Apple</a>
                                </div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#">iMac</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#">MacBook Air</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#">MacBook Pro</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#">Accessories</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Dell</a>
                                </div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#">Inspiron</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#">XPS</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Sony</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">Phones</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">LG</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Motorola</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#">Samsung</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: please include html for `#navigation`. Ideally, this would be a stripped down version of the actually html; just the pieces needed to understand the overall structure.

Comment: BTW, it says this on the treeview github page: `Note that this project is not actively maintained anymore. Check out jqTree for a more up to date plugin.` Here is [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree/).

Comment: Added the html code for you to look at it. This is the code generated by code behind class. This code is not hard coded.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Clicking the names? Persistance? One open at a time? Does none of it work?

Comment: When i click the + or - symbols the nodes are expanding and collapsing perfectly. Same thing does not work when i click on text which redirect to different page with in same site. I want this control to expand the clicked node and collapse the previous node when i click the text also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code behind generates `<div><a href="#">Marketing</a></div>`. Apparently, there is something wrong with having two levels of tags. Change the structure to just `<span>Marketing</span>` and it will work. My guess is that you could use `<a>` or `<div>` if you prefer.

I've made those changes here and it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/V7A6A/2/

Comment: No its not working even if i change the anchor tags with span tags. Same behavior.

Comment: Jquery Treeview example 3 also failing to work as i expected when i replaced their html with my span tag html.

Comment: @SurendraChatakondu where are the +/- symbols? Are they background images on the `div` tags? Can you please show the css for those?

Comment: It's the same CSS class used by Jquery treeview example. I did not modify the css class. If you still want it, let me know i can post it here.

Comment: @SurendraChatakondu OK I've updated my answer with one that should work for you. Give that a try and accept my answer if it works!

Comment: div tags were generated automatically along with a tags/span tags since this control is registered in master page and used in b/n contentplaceholder id "PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" div tag. So i can not control in generating div tags. Your solution will work if anybody using plain html. Anyway thanks for your help. We found a solution by setting the id's for each link through programatically and setting the cookie id as this id. We generated id for each a tag that should be understandable by cookie. If anybody wants the logic, i can post it here.

Comment: @SurendraChatakondu In that case, couldn't you just use javascript to change the tags before invoking the plugin? Let me know if you want me to show that code. Either way, I'm glad you got the cookies working.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery treeview example was setting the cookie when I expand each node. I built the same logic (how it used to generate the id when we click each node) in code behind for each site/page and then assigned this id to the a tag when I was generating  tag. Then in the document.ready function I wrote the following logic to set the cookie id on each  click.

```
            jQuery.fn.alertElementUrl = function()
            {
                return this.each(function()
                {
                    if(this.id == "")
                    {
                        $.cookie("treeview", $.cookie("treeview"),{path: '/'} );
                        window.location = this.href;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $.cookie("treeview", this.id.substring(this.id.lastIndexOf('_')+1),{path: '/'} );
                        window.location = this.href;
                    }
                });     
            };

            $("a").click(function ()
            {
                $(this).alertElementUrl();      

            });
```